# How can I get Tomcat to serve static content without /static/ being in the URL?

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat server where I want to serve only static content from the ROOT application. The standard is to place a file like foo.html into the `webapps/ROOT/static` folder, and then access with a link like `http://myserver:8080/static/foo.html.`

How can I configure it to remove the `/static/` portion from the public URL, but still let me put all of my static content in the static folder?

(I have lots of files with full path references in them that I can't easily change, like JavaScript with `src="/js/somefile.js"`, so I don't want to have to update them all to add /static to the beginning).

I want the server to interpret that `http://myserver:8080/foo.html` means to find it in `webapps/ROOT/static`.  But I want a link like `http://myserver:8080/myotherapp/bar.html` to continue to resolve using `webapps/myotherapp/`

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to put your static files in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT` directly?

Comment: I did end up doing that, but had kinda wanted to have a directory I could wall off and set permissions on so that my UI programmer could only write to that, and not have any chance of uploading anything harmful or wiping out WEB-INF or any of the other stuff there.

Comment: A user can not delete a non-empty directory, so `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF` can not be touched by a user with write permissions on `webapps/ROOT`, but without write permissions on `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF`. `http://myserver:8080/myotherapp/` will still resolve to `webapps/myotherapp/`, even if `/webapps/ROOT/myotherapp/` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a `RewriteValve` similar to Apache's `mod_rewrite`. You can use it twofold: at the application level or at the virtual host level.

To add the valve to the `ROOT` application add the valve to the `ROOT/META-INF/context.xml` file:

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

Then add a `ROOT/WEB-INF/rewrite.config` with the following content:

```
RewriteCond /static%{SERVLET_PATH} -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /static/$1 [L]
```

**PS**: Debugging rewrite rule can be frustrating, so a:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].rewrite.level = FINE
```

in Tomcat's `logging.properties` can help.